# Softlayer getAllBillingItems stopped working?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The following python script worked like a charm last month:

Script:

```
import SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.Client(username='someUser', api_key='someKey')
LastInvoice = client['Account'].getAllBillingItems()
print LastInvoice
```

Today's result:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/username/Documents/Python/Softlayer/Softlayer5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/Documents/Python/Softlayer/Softlayer5.py", line 8, in <module>
    LastInvoice = client['Account'].getAllBillingItems()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\API.py", line 392, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\API.py", line 360, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\API.py", line 263, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SoftLayer\transports.py", line 197, in __call__
    raise exceptions.TransportError(ex.response.status_code, str(ex))
SoftLayer.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500): 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account
```

Other api actions work fine... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the charm has a defect and it is when the response has a big amount of data, that causes timeouts in the response and the conection is closed.

but this issue can be easily solved by using result limits take a look to this example:

```
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

offset = 0
limit = 50

accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']

while True:
    try:
        result = accountService.getAllBillingItems(limit=limit, offset=offset)
        offset = offset + limit
        limit = limit + limit
        print(result)
        if not result:
            break
    except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        print("Unable to retrieve the servers . " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
        exit(1)
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a go.

Comment: great you can get more information about this error here http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/how-solve-error-fetching-http-headers the fix in all cases is to limit the amount of data in the asnwer.If this help you please do not forget mark the answer as the correct and click like :)